# On vector spaces and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question**

Suppose $V$ is the subspace of polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ and $T : V \to V$ is given by $$T[f(x)] = 2f(x) + 3f'(x).$$

1. Prove that $V$ is a vector space.
2. What is the dimension of $V$?

**My working**

I am likely going to tutor a course in linear algebra in the coming semester, so I am brushing up on my concepts right now, which are a little rusty as I last touched linear algebra more than three years ago.

Any help for parts $1$ and $2$ will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: For part (1), I suggest that you have a look at vector space definition and axioms. That will be useful in any case. For (2), what is a basis of that space.

Comment: For parts 1 and 2, you really just need the definition of a vector space and the definition of dimension (since it seems you have a basis already). Are these definitions familiar?

Comment: @IsAdisplayName For part $2$, would the dimension be $4$?

Comment: @EthanMark yes i think so too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that V is a vector space, you have 8 axioms that you must demonstrate are true.  They essentially amount to showing that the space has a property of vector addition, scalar multiplication, and scalar multiplication commutes over vector addition.

Any linear algebra book (or the internets) will have the precise formulation of the axioms.  You should have these handy if you are going to tutor.

But essentially you show that for any two polynomials of degree 3 or less, their sum is a polynomial of degree 3 or less. Addition is commutative and associative.

0 is the zero vector of the space

You can multiply a polynomial by a constant and have a polynomial of the same degree.

etc.

For the second part, a polynomial of degree 3 or less can be written as $(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3)$  How many "free" elements do you have to play with?  $(a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3).$  That is four elements, so you have a 4-dimensional space. If you have a basis, then count the number of basis vectors.